# Broadcasting multiple video streams to multiple WebRTC clients using Kurento Media Server?

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, kurento

I'm new to video streaming and I've been reading up on media servers to get a better understanding of how they work.  A customer of mine is planning to purchase approximately 48 video cameras for installation in their facility.  They haven't yet decided on the model of camera but I do know that one model they're considering outputs video in WebM format (VP8 and Vorbis or Opus).  If I understand correctly, this video format could be viewed in a browser that supports WebRTC (e.g., Chrome) without any kind of plugin.  My customer would ideally like to have their users to connect to a web site, authenticate and then see all 48 video streams displayed at a very low resolution in a grid.  Choosing a particular video stream would then display that stream at full resolution (they say 480p is the max resolution they're expecting).  As I understand it, there will be 3 - 5 users who might want to view the list of video streams simultaneously.

I've done some research into Kurento Media Server and I think I could accomplish this design using it but I'm not totally certain.  Assuming that the output of the cameras doesn't need to be transcoded to be compatible with WebRTC, I would need one WebRtcEndpoint for each camera, right?  Beyond that, I'm not exactly sure how I would I architect the media pipelines in such as way to allow multiple users to view low-res versions of all 48 video streams simultaneously?  Can anyone tell me if this is feasible with Kurento Media Server?

Comment: Hi ,
Any luck on the architecture. Because i am also trying to productionize a similar use case.